# How to access static inner Java class via Clojure interop?

Tags: java, interop, clojure

Basically what I need to do is this

```
FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY
```

I tried doing the obvious

```
(.. FileChannel MapMode READ_ONLY)
```

but that ends up throwing an exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MapMode
```

even the `/` notation specified as for access static fields in the [interop documentation](http://clojure.org/java_interop) produces the same exception

```
(. (FileChannel/MapMode) READ_ONLY)
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You access inner classes with $

```
java.nio.channels.FileChannel$MapMode/READ_ONLY
```

Mind that if you are importing `FileChannel` you should also import `FileChannel$MapMode`.

Comment: Don't forget that if you are importing FileChannel with the `import` function or with the `:import` keyword, you must also specify that you are importing `FileChannel$MapMode`

Comment: Thank you @TerjeDahl. I think you should edit your question to include this, Hamza Yerlikaya.

Comment: This is a very old question, but just in case this comment saves someone a few minutes:
when importing those nested classes, you have to make sure the nested class is defined in the class that you are importing from. If the nested class is inherited, you have to import it from the parent class.

Answer (score 16):

The syntax `(FileChannel/MapMode)` is a simplification and intended only for static fields and methods (for fields, you may even omit the parentheses)! Also the `.` and `..` forms are for fields/methods but NOT for nested/inner classes!

For the JVM, an inner class `Outer.Inner` is just a class named `Outer$Inner` (and the compiler creates a file `Outer$Inner.class` for this). The Java compiler lets you refer to it by `Outer.Inner`. You can also define a not-inner class named `Outer$Inner` to which the compiler lets you refer as `Outer$Inner`. You cannot define both at the same time, however, since both would have class names of `Outer$Inner` (and `.class` files named `Outer$Inner.class`, so this would be a duplicate class name!)

When using reflection - e.g. with `Class.forName()` - (usually to introduce some dynamicity) you cannot omit the package name of an imported class and you must use the real class name with the `$` sign instead of a dot.

Probably for its dynamic nature, Clojure takes the same approach, so you need to use the form `my.package.Outer$Inner` if the class is in `my.package` - even if you imported the outer class already! To avoid the package name, you can explicitly import the inner class `my.package.Outer$Inner` and then refer to it as `Outer$Inner` (its real class name!) but you will not reduce this to `Inner` by just importing it:

`Inner` has no meaning to the JVM, just the Java-Compiler offers you this shortcut from the compile time context (which is NOT available to the JVM and methods like `Class.forName` at runtime!) ... OK, in Clojure you could, of course, always define: `(def Inner Outer$Inner)` ... or `(def Tom Outer$Inner)` or `(def Harry Outer$Inner)` or whatever ... if you like that better.

Comment: `(def Inner Outer$Inner)` does not work for static fields of `Inner`. The following would not work: `Inner/staticField`