# Clojure Java Interop of Enum Normalizer.Form

Tags: java, unicode, clojure, enums, interop

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to use the Java interop in Clojure to normalize Unicode. I've been trying to to use [java.text.Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html), but I keep getting `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to call the enum [Normalizer.Form.NFD](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#enum.constant.summary).  Essentially, I'm just trying to do something like this in Java:

```
java.text.Normalizer.normalize("Ἑλλάς", java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

I've been trying to do something like this in Clojure, but to no avail:

```
(import java.text.Normalizer)
(java.text.Normalizer/normalize "Ἑλλάς" java.text.Normalizer.Form/NFD)
```

`Normalizer/normalize` seems to be found ok, but getting at `Normalizer.Form.NFD` seems to be the problem as I keep getting the error:

`Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException java.text.Normalizer.Form`

I'm working on Windows using: `Clojure 1.8.0` and `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_112-b15`

I went ahead and tested it in regular Java and it works fine. So the class is installed on the system.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong here?  Am I calling it incorrectly?  Is there something else I need to import perhaps?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives you trouble because `Form` is an `inner class`. In bytecode, a class `outer.inner` is actually represented as `outer$inner`. See more [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140843/how-to-access-static-inner-java-class-via-clojure-interop), and [this google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/P4asiTnvlww).

```
(import java.text.Normalizer
        java.text.Normalizer$Form)
(java.text.Normalizer/normalize "Ἑλλάς" java.text.Normalizer$Form/NFD) ;; "Ἑλλάς"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this works exactly as needed. Unfortunately, I didn't think to search for "static inner java class" after banging my head against this.  But in any case, thank you for the quick and clear response!

Comment: Glad I could help! if this answered your question, you should accept the answer :)

Comment: Done. Thank you again!